# Where can I find a single item template

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to sell just one item on my store. I am looking for something that resembles https://westcoastvapesupply.com/products/sour-worms-ejuice-by-candy-king-100ml .

I also don't want the product bar since it's just one item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WC single item template is located at:

`yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php`

See this documentation:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

So, you would want to move any of those templates to your child theme under `/wp-content/themes/your-child-theme/woocommerce/[any_template_you_want]`

So, for example, if you wanted to edit the single-product.php but safe from WC updates, you would put the file in this directory and do your mods:

`www.yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/your_child_theme/woocommerce/single-product.php`

Last thing to mention here is keep the directory structure as well.  So, if you want to edit something in the 'emails' folder, it would be like this:

`www.yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/your_child_theme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php` (just for example sake)

So, copy any templates you want to modify using that documentation above and you will be safe from any updates over time.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to edit the template for single item? Do you want to customize the template to change its look and feel?

If not, this is how you add a single item to your website -

1. Create a Product in Woocommerce
2. Copy the product URL
3. Go to Appearance > Menus
4. Locate your Primary Menu (Assuming you want to put it there)
5. Add a 'Custom Link' item to your menu. Paste the product URL in the 'URL' box.
6. SAVE YOUR MENU.

There you have it. A single product on your site linked directly from the MENU.

IF YOU ARE STILL LOOKING FOR THE TEMPLATE THEN FOLLOW THE INSTRUCTIONS BELOW -

1. Login to your Hosting account or FTP into it
2. Go to public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php

Note: Any change you make to this template will be overwritten whenever you update the Woocommerce plugin. So changes should be made through your theme's functions.php file.